# How to get updated / lastmod value for static files for sitemap Gatsby

Tags: reactjs, graphql, gatsby

I've been using Gatsby and have been trying to create a `sitemap` with `lastmod` values for static pages (`src/pages`). I saw a random code snippet in which someone ran the query below within his `gatsby-config.js` and was able to get the date he last modified them.

```
allSitePage {
  nodes {
    path
    context {
      updated
    }
  }
}
```

I've not been able to achieve the same feat.

This is what I've tried so far. I've assumed he was using a context manager and set context within his `js` files and updating the value of the context manually every time he edited the files.

```js
const Updated = React.createContext('2021-11-29')

class IndexPage extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {/* Example */}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

/* Also tried IndexPage.contextType = Updated */
IndexPage.useContext = Updated

export default IndexPage
```

I've ran the query again, but have not been able to pass the value to be seen within the `graphql` query. This is the query I ran in the Graphql playground.

```
query MyQuery {
  allSitePage {
    nodes {
      id
      context {
        updated
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is what my whole data structure looks like within the Graphql playground.
[image: data structure of graphql playground specifically allSitePage]

How would I be able to get / set a `updated` value to be used in `gatsby-config.js` when creating a sitemap?

Comment: Field SitePage.context is no longer available in GraphQL queries since Gatsby 4 ([link](https://github.com/microapps/gatsby-plugin-react-i18next/issues/143)) ([docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/release-notes/migrating-from-v3-to-v4/#field-sitepagecontext-is-no-longer-available-in-graphql-queries))

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**1. Use `gatsby-source-filesystem` to add the static page files to your filesystem so you can query them.**

In `gatsby-config.js` add the following:

```
{
  resolve: "gatsby-source-filesystem",
  options: {
    name: "pages",
    path: "./src/pages/",
  },
},
```

**Note**: Whatever you use for the `name` property here will become what you filter on in the query.

**2. Add `gatsby-transformer-gitinfo` to your project to add some git information on `File` fields from the latest commit.** ([plugin docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-transformer-gitinfo/))

Just declare it underneath step 1 like so:

```
{
  resolve: "gatsby-source-filesystem",
  options: {
    name: "pages",
    path: "./src/pages/",
  },
},
`gatsby-transformer-gitinfo`,
```

We use this plugin because any of the `modifiedTime`/`mtime`/`changeTime`/`ctime` fields in Gatsby's `File` nodes are overwritten at deploy time because git does not record or keep file timestamp metadata.

**3. Now we have all the necessary data added to GraphQL and can query it to see what it looks like:**

```
query MyQuery {
  site {
    siteMetadata {
      siteUrl
    }
  }
  allSitePage {
    nodes {
      path
    }
  }
  allFile(filter: {sourceInstanceName: {eq: "pages"}}) {
    edges {
      node {
        fields {
          gitLogLatestDate
        }
        name
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Note:** `sourceInstanceName` should equal whatever you set for `options.name` in step 1.

The query result should look something like this:

```
{
  "data": {
    "site": {
      "siteMetadata": {
        "siteUrl": "https://www.example.com"
      }
    },
    "allSitePage": {
      "nodes": [
        {
          "path": "/dev-404-page/"
        },
        {
          "path": "/404/"
        },
        {
          "path": "/404.html"
        },
        {
          "path": "/contact/"
        },
        {
          "path": "/features/"
        },
        {
          "path": "/"
        },
        {
          "path": "/privacy/"
        },
        {
          "path": "/terms/"
        }
      ]
    },
    "allFile": {
      "edges": [
        {
          "node": {
            "fields": {
              "gitLogLatestDate": "2021-12-09 23:18:29 -0600"
            },
            "name": "404"
          }
        },
        {
          "node": {
            "fields": {
              "gitLogLatestDate": "2021-12-09 23:18:29 -0600"
            },
            "name": "contact"
          }
        },
        {
          "node": {
            "fields": {
              "gitLogLatestDate": "2021-12-09 23:18:29 -0600"
            },
            "name": "privacy"
          }
        },
        {
          "node": {
            "fields": {
              "gitLogLatestDate": "2021-12-07 19:11:12 -0600"
            },
            "name": "index"
          }
        },
        {
          "node": {
            "fields": {
              "gitLogLatestDate": "2021-12-09 23:18:29 -0600"
            },
            "name": "terms"
          }
        },
        {
          "node": {
            "fields": {
              "gitLogLatestDate": "2021-12-09 23:18:29 -0600"
            },
            "name": "features"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "extensions": {}
}
```

**4. Now let's put it all together in `gatsby-config.js`:**

```
{
  resolve: "gatsby-source-filesystem",
  options: {
    name: "pages",
    path: "./src/pages/",
  },
},
`gatsby-transformer-gitinfo`,
{
  resolve: "gatsby-plugin-sitemap",
  options: {
    query: `{
      site {
        siteMetadata {
          siteUrl
        }
      }
      allSitePage {
        nodes {
          path
        }
      }
      allFile(filter: {sourceInstanceName: {eq: "pages"}}) {
        edges {
          node {
            fields {
              gitLogLatestDate
            }
            name
          }
        }
      }
    }`,
    resolvePages: ({
      allSitePage: { nodes: sitePages },
      allFile: { edges: pageFiles }
    }) => {
      return sitePages.map(page => {
        const pageFile = pageFiles.find(({ node }) => {
          const fileName = node.name === 'index' ? '/' : `/${node.name}/`;
          return page.path === fileName;
        });

        return { ...page, ...pageFile?.node?.fields }
      })
    },
    serialize: ({ path, gitLogLatestDate }) => {
      return {
        url: path,
        lastmod: gitLogLatestDate
      }
    },
    createLinkInHead: true,
  },
}
```

Explanation of the `gatsby-plugin-sitemap` options:

- `query` is self-explanatory
- `resolvePages`

  - takes in the result from the `query`, so we can use destructuring to assign the `allSitePage` and `allFile` nodes/edges to variables.
  - mapping through the `sitePages` (`allSitePage.nodes`), use the `page.path` to find the matching file `name`.

    - if the file `name` is `index` use `/` for matching since the path is not `/index/`, otherwise just wrap the file `name` in separators.
  - return the merged page object and matching file object that contains the git info
  - (the resulting array of objects from `resolvePages` becomes the `allPages` object in the plugin's code)
- `serialize`

  - This function maps through `allPages` aka the array of page objects from `resolvePages`, so we can again just use destructuring to grab each page's `path` and `gitLogLatestDate`.
  - Return properties:

    - `url`: The plugin will use `siteMetaData.siteUrl` from the query and append whatever value is assigned here to generate the full URL.
    - `lastmod`: Expects a valid time value and always outputs a full ISO8601 string regardless of the format passed in.

      **Note:** Currently, there doesn't seem to be a way to format `lastmod` as date only through `gatsby-plugin-sitemap`. This is because `gatsby-plugin-sitemap` uses this [sitemap](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sitemap) library under the hood and while some of that library's components have a `lastmodDateOnly` flag that will chop off the time string, `gatsby-plugin-sitemap` does not use them.
- `createLinkInHead`: links the sitemap index in your site's head

**5. Finally, run `gatsby build` and you should see the result show up in `public/sitemap/sitemap-0.xml`**

(Seems like `gatsby-plugin-sitemap` recently switched to this location, so could be elsewhere if you're using an older version of the plugin.)

Result should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:news="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-news/0.9"
        xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:image="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1"
        xmlns:video="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-video/1.1">
    <url>
        <loc>https://www.example.com/contact/</loc>
        <lastmod>2021-12-10T05:18:29.000Z</lastmod>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>https://www.example.com/features/</loc>
        <lastmod>2021-12-10T05:18:29.000Z</lastmod>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>https://www.example.com/</loc>
        <lastmod>2021-12-08T01:11:12.000Z</lastmod>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>https://www.example.com/privacy/</loc>
        <lastmod>2021-12-10T05:18:29.000Z</lastmod>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>https://www.example.com/terms/</loc>
        <lastmod>2021-12-10T05:18:29.000Z</lastmod>
    </url>
</urlset>
```

---

Extra, possibly helpful details - versions of everything I'm using:

```
"gatsby": "^4.0.0",
"gatsby-plugin-sitemap": "^5.3.0",
"gatsby-source-filesystem": "^4.3.0",
"gatsby-transformer-gitinfo": "^1.1.0",
```

Answer (score 1):

```
"allSitePage": {
      "nodes": [
        {
          "path": "/signup/united-states/new-york/"
        },
        {
          "path": "/signup/united-kingdom/london/"
        }
      ]
}
```

If your project have **nested page structure** than use this below code.

```js
{
  resolve: "gatsby-source-filesystem",
  options: {
    name: "pages",
    path: "./src/pages/",
  },
},
`gatsby-transformer-gitinfo`, {
  resolve: "gatsby-plugin-sitemap",
  options: {
    query: `{
      site {
        siteMetadata {
          siteUrl
        }
      }
      allSitePage {
        nodes {
          path
        }
      }
      allFile(filter: {sourceInstanceName: {eq: "pages"}}) {
        edges {
          node {
            fields {
              gitLogLatestDate
            }
            relativePath
          }
        }
      }
    }`,
    resolvePages: ({
      allSitePage: {
        nodes: sitePages
      },
      allFile: {
        edges: pageFiles
      }
    }) => {
      return sitePages.map(page => {
        const pageFile = pageFiles.find(({
          node
        }) => {
          let fileName = node.relativePath.split('.').slice(0, -1).join('.')
          fileName = fileName === 'index' ? '/' : `/${fileName.replace('/index','')}/`
          return page.path === fileName;
        });

        return { ...page, ...pageFile?.node?.fields }
      })
    },
    serialize: ({
      path,
      gitLogLatestDate
    }) => {
      return {
        url: path,
        lastmod: gitLogLatestDate
      }
    },
    createLinkInHead: true,
  },
}
```