# Gatsby-plugin-sitemap, custom config, need to integrate pages and markdown using custom resolvePages and Serialize, what does this line of code do?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, gatsby, sitemap, gatsby-plugin

just starting with javascript and react thanks to Gatsby so excuse me if this is a total newbie question. Also just starting with posting on stackoverflow, usually just consuming content, sorry about that and if my post is incomplete or unclear in anyway.

I am building a website using GatsbyJs, and want to setup a proper sitemap using gatsby-plugin-sitemap, however i am strugling to understand what the following line of code does so i can try and customize de code to do what I need, which is integrate the pages and blog posts on the sitemap, and adding a proper lastmod when applicable. I am breaking my head but cannot get the last part to work, that is, adding lastmod when it is a blog post.

```
on gatsby-config.js:
```

```
{
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-sitemap`,
      options: {

        // Exclude specific pages or groups of pages using glob parameters
        // See: https://github.com/isaacs/minimatch
        // The example below will exclude the single `path/to/page` and all routes beginning with `category`
        output: '/',
        excludes: [`/legal/*`,`/gracias`],
        query: `
        {
           site {
             siteMetadata {
               siteUrl
             }
             buildTime(formatString: "YYYY-MM-DD")
           }
           allSitePage {
             nodes {
               path
             }
           }
           allMarkdownRemark(filter: {frontmatter: {path: {regex: "/blog/"}}}) {
             nodes {
               frontmatter {
                 path
                 date
               }
             }
           }
         }
        `,

        resolvePages: ({
          allSitePage: { nodes: allPages },
          allMarkdownRemark: { nodes: allPosts },
        }) => {
          const pathToDateMap = {};

          allPosts.map(post => {
            pathToDateMap [post.frontmatter.path] = { date: post.frontmatter.date };
          });

          const pages = allPages.map(page => {
            return { ...page, ...pathToDateMap [page.path] };//what does this line of code do???
          });

          return pages;
        },
        serialize: ({ path, date, buildTime }) => {
          let entry = {
            url: path,
            changefreq: 'monthly',
            priority: 0.5,
          };

          if (date) {
            entry.priority = 0.7;
            entry.lastmod = date;
          } else {

            entry.lastmod = buildtime;

          }

          return entry;
        }

      }
    }
```

For your knowledge both develop and build are succesful, the sitemap is generated as sitemap-index and sitemap-0.xml, and the output is there but no page has lastmod on it.

Thank you all for your help,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this:

```
return { ...page, ...pathToDateMap [page.path] };
```

You are merging objects using the [spread operator (`...`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax). So, you are returning an object that is the result of all properties of the `page` and `pathToDateMap`(at `page.path` position).

For example:

```js
let person = {
    firstName: 'John',
    lastName: 'Doe',
    age: 25,
};


let job = {
    jobTitle: 'Web developer',
    location: 'USA'
};

let employee = {
    ...person,
    ...job
};

console.log(employee)
```

In the snippet above, `employee` is the result of merging `person` and `job`.

The `lastmod` parameter is not added by default unless your source has it (WordPress normally has) but you can follow this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/70297982/5585371 to create your own.

Comment: CHeers mate! thank you for your reply., I do get now the .. dots operator part. I still don't get the position part, is it a reference to the position in some array? For anyone interested, I got it working ("kind of") the way I want it with the following tweeks:

Comment: Yes, the position `[page.path]` is because previously you are setting all the pages with the date `pathToDateMap [post.frontmatter.path] = { date: post.frontmatter.date }`